# AngularJS + Spring MVC with security - where to start?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to build the front-end part of a project with Angular and a basic REST backend that also handles security.

I have very basic knowledge of Spring but haven't really worked with Spring Security.

I'm trying to find a way to build a simple REST backend that is secured. I have searched online a lot and the main thing i found was this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ . After reading it I still don't understand how I should get started.

Also, this tutorial example works with Spring Boot and it has like a class you have to run and such, but I would like the more 'classic' Spring approach combined with maven where it's java-based configs and it runs on a Tomcat, I don't really understand the main class of the Spring Boot-way anyways.

I know how to set up a Spring project with REST controllers and I can get this to work without a problem, so that's something I don't need to figure out. I do need to figure out how to add security as simple as possible. I need user authentication and all that, but I really really have not a single clue how to go about is. What is all needed for this? Are there any better (non Spring Boot) tutorials out there?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: The url has a huge explanation of things. After reading all of that, did you follow along to setup the project as suggested in the tutorial in the link?

Comment: I did but it's all spring-boot based and I'm not at all familiar with it, I'm only familiar with the classic maven-spring approach with Java-based configurations and command line control and such

Comment: It seems that the two of us have almost the same problem. I started 1 week ago, building a ''classic'' spring application with angularjs. I partly implemented spring-security, but it isn't working properly at the moment.
The tutorials I have seen were also regarding spring boot (something I don't want to use yet). I was stuck, 4 days, asking questions on SO and there were some kind people who helped me. However, it still isn't functioning as I would like it to.
I'm also using MongoDB for a database. 
Oh, and these 3 technologies are all alien to me. Well except, spring-mvc without security..

Answer (score 13):

1. **First of all**

   It will be a good thing that you know what is Spring boot ( [Advantage of spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831479/advantage-of-spring-boot/28832500#28832500.) )
2. **secondly**

   Here is some helpful resources :

   2.1 This is about the architecture 
   [Web App Architecture - the Spring MVC - AngularJs stack](http://blog.jhades.org/developing-a-modern-java-8-web-app-with-spring-mvc-and-angularjs/)

   2.2 
   [Spring Restful Web Service Example with JSON, Jackson and Client Program](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program)

   2.3 [CRUD using Spring MVC 4.0 RESTful Web Services and AngularJS](http://www.programming-free.com/2014/07/crud-springmvc-restful-webservices-angularjs.html)

   2.4 And for the security example [Spring Data REST + Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security)

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at this open source Spring + AngularJS generator JHipster

Main site: http://jhipster.github.io/

quick slides: http://jhipster.github.io/presentation/#/

Answer (score 0):

For BackEnd - Learn basic simple spring boot first and try with sample project..
For Frontend - Using Grunt and Yoeman, you can create angular project..
Have a look at this site..
https://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/

Configure backend port in gruntfile.js..
Now You can start working on both front end and backend independently..