# What should be replace by spring security jsp taglibs to use same functionality in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-security, taglib

I am new to AngularJs, working on Angular using html pages,
I have integrated spring security, 
I have added dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

In home.jsp, following code will work

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="sec"%>

<sec:authentication property="name"/> <sec:authentication property="authorities"/>
```

Now I have home.html as I am working on Angularjs
I don't know how to achive same functionality in html pages.
I want to use spring security inbuilt functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS + Spring MVC with security - where to start?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630654/angularjs-spring-mvc-with-security-where-to-start)

Comment: @Knu8 because in our project structure they don't want JSPs or the java related code to be written inside the templates.

Comment: @Zakaria maybe, but I want the way to get out of this problem. If you could help me in this.?

Comment: You can write a bare minimum jsp, just with spring code. Rest of the html you can put in a template and call it via a directive.