# For what uses Spring Boot framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What useful facilities does Spring Boot framework have, and which of these are widely applicable in practice?

Comment: You can read my article "Why SpringBoot?" which exactly describes what you want to know. http://sivalabs.in/2016/03/why-springboot/

Comment: First of all spring boot isn't a framework. https://springhow.com/spring-boot-and-spring/

Answer (score 2):

Two best things about Spring Boot are

- It's pure Java. You can run it without XML
- Built-in tomcat app server. You can run it without setting up an app server

So it's both correct and simple to use now. I recommend trying one of the many github examples, the one I want to recommend is https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ - just download the files and you can run it directly with gradle.

Answer (score 2):

The main points are the following (my opinion, which would imply that this question should be closed):

- spring-boot is the java answer to microservices
  : [why-spring-is-winning-the-microservices-game](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/why-spring-is-winning-the-microservices-game/)
- somewhat encourages the [12-factors](https://12factor.net)
- you can have a [simple working example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html#getting-started-first-application-code) with ~ 10 lines of code.
- you can launch the app from a jar (with an embedded container) or deployed as a war, with the same spring configuration. Configure once, deploy/run anywhere :)
- spring-boot `autoconfigures` many things for you: the spring configuration is much simpler
- debugging the application is as simple as executing a main method
- It's fun
- many great spring projects integrate nicely with sring-boot: `spring-cloud`, `spring-data`...
- Another SO answer: [Advantage of Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831479/advantage-of-spring-boot)

#### [What Spring says](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/06/spring-boot-simplifying-spring-for-everyone):

> Spring Boot aims to make it easy to create Spring-powered,
> production-grade applications and services with minimum fuss. It takes
> an opinionated view of the Spring platform so that new and existing
> users can quickly get to the bits they need.
>
> ...
>
> The primary goals of Spring Boot are:
>
> - To provide a radically faster and widely accessible ‘getting started’ experience for all Spring development
> - To be opinionated out of the box, but get out of the way quickly as requirements start to diverge from the defaults
> - To provide a range of non-functional features that are common to large classes of projects (e.g. embedded servers, security, metrics,
>   health checks, externalized configuration)